# External application integration with Salesforce... single logout?

Tags: integration, oauth2, connected-apps, login, logout

We have an external website that uses our Salesforce community as an identity provider. When a user clicks sign in on the external site, it redirects to our community login page in Salesforce and logs them in using a connected app OAuth flow. The external site then gets a session and token it can use to make API calls to Salesforce as that community user.

Additionally, we have some pages in our community that the external site will link to. Using the session they've authenticated they can access our community pages already logged in using frontdoor.jsp link from the external site.

When it comes to logout, 2 scenarios can occur:

1. User is in external site and clicks logout. This will call the revoke token API to end the session.
2. User is on one of our community pages after logging in through external site and being linked to that community page. On our community page they click logout. This would call the "/secur/logout.jsp" page to end the session and redirect back to the external site.

For both scenarios I'm not sure how to ensure both the external site and community site sessions are terminated together. When linking to our community pages we will use the session token received from the OAuth flow. Does revoking that session using the revoke API automatically kill the session when they are on the community page? Does using "/secur/logout.jsp" from the community page automatically kill the session from the external site? If someone logs out from the community page, how can I ensure our external site is notified so they know the session has been killed? Right now if someone logs out from the community page, they redirect to our external site which may still think the session token is valid and shows them as signed in on the external site.

Any best practices or approaches someone can share?

Thanks!